# Request for Counter Testcase with Google Foobar Question - Prepare the Bunnies Escape

Tags: breadth-first-search, dijkstra

I recently came across GoogleFoobar's problem *Prepare the Bunnies Escape*, and I submitted a Shortest Path based solution.

However, only 3 / 5 cases passed, and I am really intrigued to know why.

I have attached my code below for reference.

If anyone can "Hack" my solution / provide a countercase / tell me what I am doing wrong, that would be appreciated.

PLEASE DO NOT SEND ME IMPLEMENTATIONS, verbal explanations of my mistakes / counter tests would be appreciated.

### Thanks.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class Solution
{
    public static int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public static int dx [] = {0,0,-1,1};
    public static int dy [] = {-1,1,0,0};

    static class State implements Comparable<State>
    {
        int x,y,moves; 
        boolean wentThroughWall;
        public State(int x, int y, int moves,  boolean wentThroughWall)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.moves = moves;
            this.wentThroughWall = wentThroughWall;
        }

        public int compareTo(State other)
        {
            return moves - other.moves;
        }
    }

    public static int solution(int[][] map) 
    {
        PriorityQueue<State> enque = new PriorityQueue<State>();
        boolean visited [][] = new boolean [map.length][map[0].length];

        enque.add(new State(0, 0, 1,false));
        while(!enque.isEmpty())
        {
            State top = enque.poll();
            if(top.x == map.length - 1 && top.y == map[0].length - 1)
            {
                ans = Math.min(ans, top.moves);
                continue;
            }

            if(visited[top.x][top.y])   
                continue;
            visited[top.x][top.y] = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++)
            {
                int nx = top.x + dx[i];
                int ny = top.y + dy[i];
                if(nx < 0 || nx >= map.length || ny < 0 || ny >= map[0].length || (map[nx][ny] == 1 && top.wentThroughWall))
                    continue;

                if(map[nx][ny] == 1)
                    enque.add(new State(nx, ny, top.moves + 1, true));
                else    
                    enque.add(new State(nx, ny, top.moves + 1, top.wentThroughWall));
            }    
        }

        return ans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] test = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
        System.out.println(Solution.solution(test));
    }

}
```

Statement: 
You're awfully close to destroying the LAMBCHOP doomsday device and freeing Commander Lambda's bunny prisoners, but once they're free of the prison blocks, the bunnies are going to need to escape Lambda's space station via the escape pods as quickly as possible. Unfortunately, the halls of the space station are a maze of corridors and dead ends that will be a deathtrap for the escaping bunnies. Fortunately, Commander Lambda has put you in charge of a remodeling project that will give you the opportunity to make things a little easier for the bunnies. Unfortunately (again), you can't just remove all obstacles between the bunnies and the escape pods - at most you can remove one wall per escape pod path, both to maintain structural integrity of the station and to avoid arousing Commander Lambda's suspicions.

You have maps of parts of the space station, each starting at a prison exit and ending at the door to an escape pod. The map is represented as a matrix of 0s and 1s, where 0s are passable space and 1s are impassable walls. The door out of the prison is at the top left (0,0) and the door into an escape pod is at the bottom right (w-1,h-1).

Write a function solution(map) that generates the length of the shortest path from the prison door to the escape pod, where you are allowed to remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans. The path length is the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance and exit nodes. The starting and ending positions are always passable (0). The map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need to remove a wall. The height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20. Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are allowed.

## Languages

To provide a Python solution, edit solution.py
To provide a Java solution, edit Solution.java

## Test cases

Your code should pass the following test cases.
Note that it may also be run against hidden test cases not shown here.

-- Python cases --
Input:
solution.solution([[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]])
Output:
    7

Input:
solution.solution([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Output:
    11

-- Java cases --
Input:
Solution.solution({{0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 0}})
Output:
    7

Input:
Solution.solution({{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}})
Output:
    11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sike, I fixed it. I managed to generate a bunch of testcases using a random test case generator, and realized that my visited array isn't defined correctly.

I have listed the correct solution below for reference with the fix.

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class Solution
{
    public static int ans = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public static int dx [] = {0,0,-1,1};
    public static int dy [] = {-1,1,0,0};

    static class State implements Comparable<State>
    {
        int x,y,moves; 
        boolean wentThroughWall;
        public State(int x, int y, int moves,  boolean wentThroughWall)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.moves = moves;
            this.wentThroughWall = wentThroughWall;
        }

        public int compareTo(State other)
        {
            return moves - other.moves;
        }
    }

    public static int solution(int[][] map) 
    {
        PriorityQueue<State> enque = new PriorityQueue<State>();
        boolean visited [][][] = new boolean [map.length][map[0].length][2];

        enque.add(new State(0, 0, 1,false));
        while(!enque.isEmpty())
        {
            State top = enque.poll();
            if(top.x == map.length - 1 && top.y == map[0].length - 1)
            {
                ans = Math.min(ans, top.moves);
                continue;
            }

            if(visited[top.x][top.y][(top.wentThroughWall ? 0 : 1)])   
                continue;

            visited[top.x][top.y][(top.wentThroughWall ? 0 : 1)] = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < dx.length; i++)
            {
                int nx = top.x + dx[i];
                int ny = top.y + dy[i];
                if(nx < 0 || nx >= map.length || ny < 0 || ny >= map[0].length || (map[nx][ny] == 1 && top.wentThroughWall))
                    continue;

                if(map[nx][ny] == 1)
                    enque.add(new State(nx, ny, top.moves + 1, true));
                else    
                    enque.add(new State(nx, ny, top.moves + 1, top.wentThroughWall));

            }    
        }

        assert(ans != Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return ans;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] test = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
        System.out.println(Solution.solution(test));
    }

}
```

As a competitive person myself, I would like to know if my code really works, or was it just weak testing.

If you find a testcase which breaks my code, please let me know in the comments and I will get back to you ASAP.

Comment: Your code works perfectly! All test cases passed.